# Complete a VBA Find Function to search for either one of two search varibles, then select the first one that comes up

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have the following:

```
Set FindRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Schedule").Range("n1:"& ActiveCell.Address).Find(What:="Assembly", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
```

I would like to do the following

```
Set FindRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Schedule").Range("n1:"& ActiveCell.Address).Find(What:="Assembly" or "Component", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
```

I would like it to search for either Assembly or Component and stop the search on whatever one comes first.

Thanks

Comment: I think you have to do separate Finds and then compare the row of each found value. The lower value will be the first one found. Or you could use an array formula as long as both values will be in the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thee may be ton's of variations.

If you are starting at N1, then you could use the entire column.

`Evaluate("MIN(MATCH(""Assembly"",N:N,0),MATCH(""Component"",N:N,0))")`

combined in a vba

```
    Sub Button1_Click()
    s = "N" & Evaluate("MIN(MATCH(""Assembly"",N:N,0),MATCH(""Component"",N:N,0))")
    MsgBox s
    Range(s).Select
    End Sub
```